# Create grid cells and sum values within each cell

Tags: r

I have a data frame of latitude, longitude and value corresponding to each location. I want to create square grid cells on the map and sum up values within each square grid cell.
I am using stat_summary2d currently to do this :

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, aes(x = LAT, y = LONG, z = VALUE)) + stat_summary2d(fun=sum)
```

But this creates rectangle cells. I want to create square cells and control the size of the square and also show the grid lines. How  can I do this ?